# Dynamics AX 2009 / BizTalk Server 2013 Compatibility

Tags: compatibility, biztalk, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, biztalk-2013

Is BizTalk Server 2013 compatible with the Dynamics AX 2009 AIF BizTalk Adapter?

I've searched but can't find any information to say either way.
I found that BizTalk Server 2010 is compatible with AX2009 SP1 RU7: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2011/09/29/microsoft-biztalk-server-2010-passes-compatibility-testing-with-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2009-sp1.aspx

(Apologies if this is not the correct site for this question, as it's not directly programming related; however I couldn't find another Stack Exchange site which looked more suitable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find anything newer announced at Partner Source.

This does not imply that BizTalk 2013 is not compatible, only that it is not a tested scenario, and that if you choose to use, it is your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the BizTalk+AX story has alwasy been a little mysterious in terms of what exactly is 'supported' and not.

However, the Adapter interface is unchanged from BizTalk Server 2010 to BizTalk Server 2013 so the '2010' Adapter should run without issue in 2013.

Worst case, PSS will only offer 'best effort' support, though it's highly unlikely you'd ever need it.